# How do I use a Java MessageFormat choice with a boolean?

Tags: java, boolean, messageformat

Assume I want to say "Your order qualifies for a discount" or "Your order does not qualify for a discount".

I assumed I could use a `choice` with a boolean value in a MessageFormat, such as

```
"Your order {0,choice,false#does not qualify|true#qualifies} for a discount"
```

But I get the error

```
Choice Pattern incorrect: false#does not qualify|true#qualifies
```

Of course, there are many other ways I could achieve this, but does a MessageFormat choice not support boolean values?

Comment: I maybe wrong, but I think ChoiceFormat only works for numeric values

Comment: @jhamon You're not wrong. ["A ChoiceFormat allows you to attach a format to a range of numbers"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html#ChoiceFormat(java.lang.String)). OP, you could convert your boolean to a number first (i.e. 0 and 1). Kinda hacky but hey

Comment: `ChoiceFormat` seems to work with `Enum`s too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChoiceFormat` does not work with `boolean` unfortunately, as others have mentioned. It seems there was at least one old JDK enhancement request to support this functionality, but it was rejected:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4682566

As such, you can use workarounds such as converting the boolean to a number first.